# How to add sequential numbers to an existing table?

Tags: oracle

I'm seeking your support as I'm new in using Toad.
I need to insert sequence numbers based on columns `subno` and `AR_INVDATE`.
So if the same `subno` has more than one `AR_INVDATE` then I need a sequential number based on sorting the `AR_INVDATE` in ascending order.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generate the numbers:

```
select subno, ar_invdate, row_number() over (partition by subno order by ar_invdate) as num from first_second_bill_v4;
```

Update the table with these numbers:

```
merge into first_second_bill_v4 t1 using (select subno, ar_invdate, row_number() over (partition by subno order by ar_invdate) as num from first_second_bill_v4) t2 on (t1.subno = t2.subno and t1.ar_invdate = t2.ar_invdate)
when matched then update set t1.num = t2.num;
```

Theoretically, not tested.